# Firefox downloads(tries to open) .zip file as .HTM

Tags: php, html, firefox, download, http-headers

I am creating downloadable zip file, it works fine almost everywhere. But in Mozilla Firefox on save  of this zip I get strange message that my_zip.zip is HTM file (sorry for the language, but I hope it is pretty understandable):
[image]

If I choose save option it will be saved as normal zip (no sign of HTM at all), but in "open as" section there are only programms for opening HTM

So, *the question is* **How to make Firefox detect this zip as zip?**
I am currently using this headers (set by PHP):

```
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zipFileName");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store");
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipFileName));
        readfile($zipFileName);
```

Already tried using `header("Content-Type: application/zip");` , does not work; plus `application/zip` is not standart (as I read here in some headers related question).
I am using **Mozilla Firefox v40.0.3**, the php project is using Laravel 5.1 *(I doubt it has anything to do with this)*

---

**UPDATE:**
While trying different `application\[format]`s , I added a dump and die command after headers

```
        //bunch of kosher headers here...
        readfile($zipFileName);
        dd(headers_list());//dumps and dies
```

And I get a zip type in download window. Then I figured out that after `die` or `exit` I will always get right download type of zip; Then I deleted all dump-and-die sections , but download type remains as zip. I have no idea what i have fixed by this manipulations.
*I would love to have an explanation of this strange situation*

Comment: Could be either firefox attachment type (see in options) or windows filetype issue (see in control panel). Apparently it's detected as zip as 7zip is suggested (by extension).

Comment: @DeDee the 7zip console was chosen by me. By default Firefox suggests default browser to open htm

Comment: "_Then I deleted all dump-and-die sections , but download type remains as zip_". That totally looks like firefox local cache, unless you use PHP caching explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

A quick [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=application/octet-stream%20sending%20zip%20file) suggests  the Content-Type seems to be the culprit

```
 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
```

Try setting it to application/x-zip-compressed ? 
ALso the comments in this bug  report may be useful: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=540900

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for response, I have updated my question , could you please check it, I have fixed the issue but i don`t undestand _how_?

Comment: As suggested by DeDee, there can caching at play here. Also instead of dumping headers, firebug can be used (network tab) to see details of the request/response.